# Is Q_PROPERTY a function-like macro in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, macros

In my opinion,the using of a function-like macro in C++ is similar to the using of a common function. It seems to be like this:

`macroFunctionName(arg1, arg2, arg3);`

However, the using of Q_PROPERTY usually looks like this:

`Q_PROPERTY(Qt::WindowModality windowModality READ windowModality WRITE setWindowModality)`

As we can see, they are different.There is no comma in the using of Q_PROPERTY.I have never seen a function-like macro which was used like Q_PROPERTY.I am even not sure whether Q_PROPERTY is a function-like macro in C++.So is it ill-formed in C++? Or it's just a special syntax for MOC in Qt?

I tried to find it in the C++ standard document but nothing about it was found.

Comment: Related: [What is the significance of Q_PROPERTY in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21965777/430766)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked in Qt's `./src/corelib/kernel/qobjectdefs.h` file for the definition, and it looks like this:

```
#define Q_PROPERTY(...) QT_ANNOTATE_CLASS(qt_property, __VA_ARGS__)
```

... which would make [Q_PROPERTY](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) a variadic macro.  Of course all it does is expand out to `QT_ANNOTATE_CLASS`, which is a different macro, one that Qt's `moc` utility presumably knows how to handle in a meaningful way when generating its `moc_*.cpp` files.

As for the use of spaces rather than commas; you're right, the preprocessor doesn't treat spaces as argument-separators.  I suspect that the C++ preprocessor is simply passing the entire line (i.e. "Qt::WindowModality windowModality READ windowModality WRITE setWindowModality") into the `QT_ANNOTATE_CLASS` macro as a single argument, and that moc's `QT_ANNOTATE_CLASS` macro-definition is doing some [stringification preprocessor tricks](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/cpp/Stringification.html) in order to parse it as a string-argument.

Comment: I suspect `READ`, `WRITE`, and all the other tags you can put in that line, are macros themselves, possibly containing commas themselves.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't thought of that possibility... that might be what they are doing, although a recursive grep of the Qt headers doesn't immediately turn up anything like `#define READ do_something_clever,`

Comment: `READ` is not a macro. `QT_ANNOTATE_CLASS` expands to nothing, so the compiler ends up seeing nothing. The purpose of `Q_PROPERTY` is for `moc` to parse it.